# Excel VBA: Delete blank columns & entire rows if specific columns are blank on specific worksheet not working

Tags: vba, excel, macros

My problem is the macro won't work on a specified worksheet, only the active one. I have two subroutines for deleting entire columns, and then deleting entire rows if specific columns are blank. I want to make it work for a specific worksheet, which I understood to be `With Worksheets("OutPut")` but it still culls the active worksheet.

It works as intended so long as the active worksheet is selected.

```
Sub DeleteBlankColumns()
    With Worksheets("OutPut")
        Set MyRange = Worksheets("OutPut").UsedRange
        For iCounter = MyRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
            If Application.CountA(Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
            Columns(iCounter).Delete
            End If
        Next iCounter
        End With
End Sub
```

And

```
Sub QuickCull()
    With Worksheets("OutPut")
        On Error Resume Next
        Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        On Error Resume Next
        Columns("C").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        On Error Resume Next
        Columns("D").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        On Error Resume Next
        Columns("E").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
End Sub
```

There's a button to `Call` both of them, which again, will work if the worksheet I want to transform is active. For reference, this is intended to be appended on an existing company macro, so simply running it on the worksheet when it's active won't work.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to put `.` infront of all the range object tied to the sheet to which you refer with the `With`.  for example `Application.CountA(.Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn)`

Comment: @ScottCraner pls make that an answer. I only saw your comment after I wrote my answer, but you deserve it

Comment: @iDevlop keep your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first code sample,

```
If Application.CountA(Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
     Columns(iCounter).Delete
```

should be

```
If Application.CountA(.Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
     .Columns(iCounter).Delete
```

(a "." before Columns, to specify the sheet)

Same thing for the second code sample

Comment: That worked perfectly for the columns, but I must be missing something from the rows? I would modify it like this, right?         `Columns("B").SpecialCells(.xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: @AlivePresumably the `.` goes in front of Columns("B") not xlBlanks.

Comment: Thank you! There was one other thing I had to change, in case anyone else has this specific problem: for my purposes, I was dealing with data that could look slightly different when it transformed. I had to add `.UsedRange` onto With `Worksheets("OutPut")` to make it: With `Worksheets("OutPut").UsedRange`,